# How to intergrate sugar CRM by keep all old data

Tags: php, wordpress, sugarcrm, orchardcms-1.6

I have a old sugar CRM and I would like to upgrade it to the latest version i mean intergrated it and keep all the old data what should i do ?
I am happy for hearing from all of you! thanks!

Comment: Which version of Sugar are you using? Have you tried upgrading using the wizard?

Comment: I am using 6.3.0RC2(sugar CRM enterprise) and want to upgrade to 6.5.12(sugar CRM enterprise)

Answer (score 0):

It depend on how old your current version is.

The common way:

1. Install new version on the different place.
2. Export all your data to CSV from old version.
3. Import all data to new version, the import manager will ask you to match fields if there will be a difference between them.
4. Check the new version if it works, give the access to your clients and close the old site.

You will need to turn off for maintenance the old version while you are doing export/import to avoid customers to insert new data.